# Imagemagick unwanted black background on rotated transparent images

Tags: background, imagemagick, rotation

I have a website that generates polaroid-like images stacked on eachother at different angles.
Up until now everything worked well, but now i've started getting some black background around my transparent .png's.
You can see the problem [here](http://trixi.deweb.ro/). The images in the last album are all messed up.

I'm using imagemagick (6.5.4.7-3.fc12).

my commands look something like this:
the first one is contained whitin a foreach and generates a bunch of pngs rotated at different angles
`convert '{$sf}' -auto-orient -thumbnail 120x120 -gravity center -bordercolor snow -background black -polaroid {$angle} {$i}.png`

the second command takes the previously generated images and stacks them toghater
`convert '*.png' -background transparent -alpha on -gravity center -layers merge -extent 190x190 +repage -thumbnail 115x115 -gravity center -extent 120x120 'result.png'`

As far as I got with the debuging, the black background is already present in the images generated with the first command and they only appear when I rotate the images. If I only use `-polaroid 0` instead of the `+polaroid`, then the resulting images are ok.
My guess is that the problem is not with the code itself, but rather ImageMagick or something else got upgraded on my server and that started this whole mess.

I also tried all kinds of combinations with setting `-alpha` and everything else i could find in the imagemagick docs that is even just slightly related to transparency, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all sorts of testing I finally got to the conclusion that the problem was not with my `convert` commands.

The solution to my problem was to reinstall/update ImageMagick.

Answer (score 1):

//It romove the unwanted black/white background and make it transparent backgraund.

```
            ImageInfo info1 = new ImageInfo(
            "/opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.18/webapps/newcpclient_branch/upload/sample/ATT00003.jpg");
    MagickImage blankImage = new MagickImage(info1);

    **blankImage.setBackgroundColor(PixelPacket.queryColorDatabase("#FFFF8800"));**

    blankImage = blankImage.rotateImage(250.0);
    blankImage.setFileName("/opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.18/webapps/newcpclient_branch/upload/sample/transparent.png");
    blankImage.writeImage(info1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have -background set to 'black' in your first line. That means you don't get transparency. Does it work if you set it to 'none'?

**Edit:**

```
import os
import random as ra

for i in range(10):
    image = 'convert C:/image.png -auto-orient -thumbnail 120x120 -gravity center -bordercolor snow -background none -polaroid '+str(ra.uniform(0,360))+' C:/test/image_polaroid_'+str(i)+'.png'
    os.system(image)

image = 'convert -size 500x500 xc:transparent C:/test/result.png'
os.system(image)

for i in range(10):
    image = 'composite -gravity center C:/test/image_polaroid_'+str(i)+'.png C:/test/result.png C:/test/result.png'
    os.system(image)
```

**Edit 2:**

```
import os
import random as ra

for i in range(10):
    image = 'convert C:/image.png -background none -polaroid 0 C:/test/image_polaroid_'+str(i)+'.png'
    os.system(image)
    image = 'mogrify -rotate '+str(ra.randint(0,360))+' -background none C:/test/image_polaroid_'+str(i)+'.png'
    os.system(image)
```

Comment: that background (as far as i know) is set for the polaroid shadow... but i already tried setting that to 'none' and 'transparent' just to make sure, with the same result. Nothing i change seem to have any effect on it.

Comment: @JoeBlack If you add '-alpha on' in the first line it also doesn't work?

Comment: '-alpha on' does not help either, nor '-alpha set' just like none of the other -alpha settings do (tried them all already).

Comment: @JoeBlack Could you do me a favour and try out the code in my edited answer and see if this works for you? It's for python, so you'll have to adapt it a bit.

Comment: OK, after a bit of thinkering I managed to try your code, but it results in a blank (fully transparent) png. I'm going to keep on trying some other variations with it too.

Comment: Also, the images still have the black background after applying the `xc:transparent` to the them.

Comment: The 'xc:transparent' is only for the creation of one blank canvas to paste all other images on; seems like -composite doesn't work and you only get the canvas. Try these on your polaroided images: create a transparent canvas:"convert -size 1000x1000 xc:transparent {$canvas}"; paste one image after another on the canvas: "composite -gravity center {$i} {$canvas} {$canvas}". Try to give the full path on the $i's and $canvas. Also to composite if possible. But since you're using a version from 2009 I assume you don't control your instance of imagemagick and also can't upgrade. Is that correct?

Comment: I do have root access, but I only have limited knowledge of how to do stuff on the server, basicly I know how to do some basic stuff and use yum and I did manage to compile a few stuff myself, but thats about it. About yum, when i try upgrading ImageMagick, it says there is no upgrade for it.. I guess fc12 is not all that well supported anymore. Anyways, if you have any suggestions about what could I try or test for on the server, just let me know.

Comment: Have you tried installing it like this: $ rpm -Uvh ImageMagick-6.7.5-6.i386.rpm ? (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#unix)

Comment: Since you said it worked with -polaroid 0 I put some new code up that creates the polaroids and then rotates them (Edit 2). Do you still have the black boxes with this?

Comment: The code suggestion from edit 2 did not solve the problem. I still get the black background. Which in my opinion just prooves that the problem lies somewhere else. I tried installing it from rpm, but got some dependency problems like: libHalf.so.4, libIex.so.4, libIlmImf.so.4 etc.. i will try to install the latest ImageMagick release and try again then.