# No transparency with Imagick polaroid effect

Tags: php, imagemagick

I use the below code to create *polaroid effect*, but its really distracted without any transparent effect around.

```
<?php
/* Create the object */
$image = new Imagick('wood.png');

/* Set the opacity */
$image->polaroidImage(new ImagickDraw(), 25);

/* output the image */
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;

?>
```

I get result like http://photoapp.biz/polaroid/test.php

Orginal image is http://photoapp.biz/polaroid/wood.png

What will be the problem? This occurs in almost all 10 images I've tried.

Example:

[image]

Comment: i tried installing several php versions,all same problem

Comment: Where exactly should be transparent?

Comment: there should be no blackand white colour around

Comment: See the duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9276975/imagemagick-unwanted-black-background-on-rotated-transparent-images

Answer (score 0):

Transparency is set with [Imagick::setImageOpacity](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageopacity.php)

```
$image->setImageOpacity(0.7);
```

Besides maybe you need to work with another image format:

> That said, some web browsers however do NOT display transparent "PNG"
>   images correctly (most notably Microsoft Internet Explorer v6, though
>   IE v7 does). Because of this I generally prefer to use JPEG and GIF
>   image formats, and only use PNG when generating images with
>   semi-transparent pixels, or requiring a exact colors for later
>   examples.

Source: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/#PNG

**EDIT 1**

try

> $image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));

Comment: I am asking for transparancy around the image

Comment: Ah yes, Downloading images I can see what you mean.I edited your post to show it...

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but you are really asking about anti aliasing, aren't you?

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/antialiasing/

Comment: yea ... something like that...unwanted part need to be removed

Answer (score 0):

Try this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageantialias.php.

What it does is:

[image]

Just be aware that IMAGIC can be compiled in many different ways and you might have different effects across different environments.